# commercetools: Insufficient scope on request

Tags: commercetools

When I try to fetch products then I get the error message "Insufficient scope":

```
curl -vsH "Authorization: Bearer MY_ACCESS_TOKEN" https://api.sphere.io/MY_PROJECT/products
```

output:

```
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 162.13.76.39...
* Connected to api.sphere.io (162.13.76.39) port 443 (#0)
> GET /MY_PROJECT/products HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.37.1
> Host: api.sphere.io
> Accept: */*
> Authorization: Bearer MY_ACCESS_TOKEN
>
< HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
<
Insufficient scope
```

[The question originated from an internal support request.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error message appears when a token is invalid for a commercetools project, for example it is for another project.

To recover from this problem [create a new token for the project](http://dev.commercetools.com/curl-cheatsheet.html#get-token).